# Unicode characters in answer garble the entire page

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design, unicode, posting

Over on *Science Fiction & Fantasy*, we've had a couple of answers containing some Unicode characters that spilled over onto the rest of the page.

[image: screenshot of a weird looking page]

The comments were deleted *and* edited to push the offending bit into history, [as discussed on our meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8152/19561).

So the direct problem has been solved.

However, should Unicode characters in a post be able to do this? Should the contents of an element be allowed to draw *outside the boundaries* of that element?
(I think they should not, hence this bug report).

Comment: This is rare enough that manual handling of such issues is seen as enough. If it becomes a real problem, we will work to fix it.

Comment: I don't understand why there's a need for browsers or any software to support stacking the Unicode characters so heavily. Cut it off at 3 or 4, whatever's realistic for actual language. (It does seem to be a problem for browsers, rather than SE, to fix)

Comment: @CreationEdge: I don't understand why there is a need to cut it off.

Comment: @sumelic Because it's ugly, stupid, ruins text fields as seen, and serves no linguistic purposes? It's essentially a universal bug.

Comment: @CreationEdge: It's not a bug. People can do plenty of ugly things with Unicode, or with just ASCII for that matter. As Oded said, it's not a real problem at the moment.

Comment: @sumelic I'm talking about web browsers, not SE.

Comment: @oded just to know, it is appropriate to flag such kind of post for removal, right?

Comment: @SPArchaeologist - given that don't add any value and are just trolling, yeah, absolutely.

Comment: @oded - good to know, will start doing so. I will probably skip them if they are trying to demonstrate a bug but otherwise unless it is some small joke, they will have to go.